# how to download the image automatically without opening the pages and clicking the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <button id="download-btn">download</Button>


</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#download-btn').click(function () {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = 'http://cyimg44.cyworld.com/common/file_down.asp?redirect=%2F440022%2F2017%2F8%2F6%2F14%2FDSC%5F2087%5F8%5F6155677001240%2Ejpg';  // use realtive url 
            link.download = 'MyToy.jpeg';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        });
    })
</script>

</html>
```

I can go to the web page and download the image by clicking the right button and clicking the save as ...

But I have a lot of image links.

I don't want to go to another web page. I want to download directly after clicking the button.

Can I do that?? Is is possible??

Answer (score 2):

Could you just use the "a" tag with the download option ?

`<a href="/images/somecoolimage.jpg" download>Download</a>`

You could style it  to look like a button if that is what you want

Comment: Whoa, I never stumbled about this little gem of an attribute. This is way easier than controlling headers of the files to be downloaded, and should answer the question perfectly IMO. Browser support is broad (except IE11, but that's dead anyway). Thank you @Piyper!

Comment: I just tried but I can go to the link only not to download..

Comment: As Sebastian B. stated, if you are using older browsers, you maybe not have the best support for it, what browser are you trying this with  Hyunmyung Kim?

Comment: oh and you are serving this file up using a program vs letting the webserver server up the file. in that case, most likely your asp program is not setting the mime type properly. that download option is only as good as the information provided, so if you not using "image/jpg" as a mime type for the returning stream, you will get spotty results, Chrome seems to always figure out the correct mime type, Edge, not so much